# How to set default value for configuration field with type image

Tags: magento2

I have `system.xml` with some fields:

```
<field id="image_width" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Image width</label>
</field>
<field id="image_height" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Image height</label>
</field>
<field id="placeholder_image" translate="label comment" type="image" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Image placeholder</label>
    <comment>Allowed file types:PNG, GIF, JPG, JPEG, SVG.</comment>
    <backend_model>MyNamespace\MyModule\Model\Config\Backend\Image\Placeholder</backend_model>
    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">module_folder</base_url>
</field>
```

And i set default values for them in `config.xml`:

```
<image_width>100</image_width>
<image_height>100</image_height>
<placeholder_image>placeholder.gif</placeholder_image>
```

The problem is in `placeholder_image` field. My placeholder image lies in `app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/view/frontend/web/images/placeholder.gif` and Magento 2 looks for it in `pub/media/module_folder/placeholder.gif`. How can i tell magento to copy it from my folder to pub/media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have this code in one of your custom extensions.
You can use the `Setup/InstallData.php` or `Setup/UpgradeData.php` files that run when you install or upgrade the module and place an image inside the folder you need.

Comment: OP wants to set default values via module configxml

Comment: @MagePsycho. Yep. And this would work. Set the default value in `config.xml` then use the install/upgrade scripts to place that specific image into the desired folder.

Comment: I think this is the only solution for now, so i accept it, but it would be great to have possibility to use something like `<placeholder_image>Namespace_ModuleName::placeholder.gif</placeholder_image>` in `config.xml`.